# How do you turn on the fast walking ability on Smart Moving Mod?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I tried to do "O" and "I" but they made only me slower. I'm trying to find out how to go *faster* not slower.

Answer (score 2):

## Controls

Here is a quote from the [*Official mod page*](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/361430-172forge-smart-moving/):

> Faster Sprinting and Exhaustion
>
> This mod implements a faster, optional, configurable sprinting and exhaustion  behaviour. It is merged with the standard minecraft sprinting and hunger behavior.
>
> ***To sprint you have to move forward and click and hold the sprint button (default "TAB")***. >Sprinting is currently possible for walking, swimming diving, crawling, and climbing.
>   Sprinting optionally causes exhaustion and will automatically end when a certain configurable threshold is reached.
>
> ***To change this default sprint button visit Minecrafts "Options"/"Controls" menu.***

I have bold & emphasized the things probably needed for you.